# Are vendor specific style prefixes needed any more on most common CSS3 properties?

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

I guess most of us are used to write common CSS3 properties with vendor specific prefixes to support all browsers, so it's not uncommon to see something like this:

```
border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-o-border-radius: 6px;
```

I recently noticed that on most common properties the prefix is not required any more. And given the rapid update cycle of current browsers, I started to think about the necessity of keeping the prefixes - e.g. there probably are not many versions of Chrome still in the wild that do not support the native `border-radius` syntax.

Also I've always thought of these kind of properties as just eye candy, so I don't think there would be any problem about dropping support for the now obsolete Firefox 3.* and the likes in this regard.

So, is it safe to drop the prefixes on most common properties, namely `border-radius` and `box-shadow`?

Comment: Most are still needed. Chrome has started to use the main attribute, but most aren't fully supported without the vendor prefix.

Comment: To keep it short: yes, it is safe to drop them.

Comment: Yep, I realize that on some more exotic properties they are still required but it appears that the most recent version of every major browser supports the `border-radius` syntax natively, for example.

Comment: Best to put the non-vendor rule (`border-radius: 6px;` last. That future-proofs things.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20721343/165673