# Do I still need to use prefixes with CSS3 features?

Tags: css, cross-browser, vendor-prefix

For example with box-shadow or transition, do I still need to use prefixes like "moz" or "webkit?" It seems... odd, and at least on Firefox on Unix, it works perfectly without any prefixes.

Comment: use them just to be safe.. at best they'll be ignored.. at least you wont disappoint customers..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are vendor specific style prefixes needed any more on most common CSS3 properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261208/are-vendor-specific-style-prefixes-needed-any-more-on-most-common-css3-propertie), [How do I find out when I can safely drop vendor prefixes for a CSS3 property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211602/how-do-i-find-out-when-i-can-safely-drop-vendor-prefixes-for-a-css3-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : **Use Them** because **HTML5** and **CSS3** are still **under development** and are not fully supported by any browser.

Other stuff you may like to read : As a developer, we need to see from user point of view, cross-browser compatibility is essential to maintain your website layout almost same in all browsers, more over it also gives professional edge to your work if your layout is consistent in all browser, using proprietary properties won't increase your page load time, and most of the users don't update their browsers to latest version, and so they get a shabby rendered page, so to be safe use them unless and until CSS3 and HTML5 are completely supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on which browsers you need to support. CSS 3 features only work in browsers that support CSS 3, fully or partially.

Some browsers support features outside the standards by using prefixes. Some of those features end up in the standards, and newer versions support those features both with and without prefix, and later on only without the prefix.

You just have to add different versions of the same CSS for the different browsers that you support, and update the style sheets when the browsers are updated.

Comment: Why would I need to update the stylesheet when the browsers are updated? Some users would keep using the old browsers even in 2017, those extra lines do no harm, do they? As I see it, the only problem is to not forget to put put them and spend extra time writing the extra lines.

Comment: @Jack: Browsers add and remove support for styles with new versions, sometimes even changes what they do. Most of the time obsolete rules is no problem, but when you use styles that are on the edge you have to keep up with updates and check that the rules still work in various browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I would say keep putting the prefix for now.
Some legacy browsers are still using them and are unfortunately used by a lot of users.
**Example, Prefix is needed for:**

- *border-radius*  (Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6)
- *box-shadow* (Saf3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+)