# Is there a browser-compatibility deprecation table for CSS3 vendor prefixes?

Tags: w3c, css

Would anyone here post a site that presents a neat summary of which vendor specific CSS3 extensions - e.g. `-moz-border-radius` - are still required or can be deprecated?

From what I have seen by and large all recent versions of Chrome, Safari and Opera (forget IE, I can live without it for my current app) are by and large happy to live with the W3C attributes with no vendor prefixes.

Comment: Believe it or not, IE has *never* needed a prefix for border-radius.

Comment: !!!!.  I have often wondered at the perversity of whoever first decided that a prefix was required

Comment: Prefixes are useful for experimental or substandard implementations (try -moz-border-radius in Firefox 2 to see what I mean), it just happens that they take too long to be unprefixed...

Comment: Yes, I see now.  Took me a while to pin down a version of Firefox 2

Comment: @BoltClock The idea behind was that the implementation of standards simply took too long for companies & at the same time giving devs kinda clarity on what's part of the standard and what's not. A strongly discussed/partly misunderstood topic was Hixie's outlining of HTML5's final recommendation date & full implementation by at least 2(!) browser by *2022*! The earliest CSS 3 drafts were published in 1999. As H. Sivonen points out in a blog entry, the idea of vendor prefixes for non-standard elements (not CSS only) has been dating back till 1998. https://hsivonen.fi/vendor-prefixes/

Comment: Why was this closed? :/

Comment: @Alex It's on hold, for being supposedly too broad... I suppose unor's change to the title improved the question, but also made it too broad and somewhat deviating from the original question you placed a bounty on. I have re-edited it to try and address animuson's concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They also have it in book form, The Book of CSS3 by Peter Gasston, that has tables listing all the CSS3 browser support. However I bet thats the last thing you wanted to look for... so [this maybe?](http://caniuse.com/)

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect I have run into caniuse in the past but it has never been something I have retained - well worth doing though.  What prompted my original question was discovering that even in its latest incarnation Firefox does not like W3C border-radius

Comment: It is a very weird thing to be sure haha

Answer (score 11):

I suggest using the [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/) site to check this.

The short answer is that you need vendor prefixes for everything that ever used them --- with the caveat that it depends on how far back you want to support old browser versions.

The CanIUse site contains browser support tables for virtually every browser feature you can imagine, and pretty much every browser you would want to support. It includes notes where particular browsers support a feature but require a vendor prefix.

You can use these tables to decide for yourself which prefixes are worth keeping and which you can drop.

Since you've asked specifically about `border-radius`, let's look at the support table for it: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

This shows us that no *current* browser version requires a prefix. But Firefox needed the prefix up to v3.6, Chrome up to 4.0, and Safari up to 4.0. Mobile Safari (3.2) and Android Browser (2.1) also show up in the list.

If you need to support those browser versions or earlier, then you need the prefixes. Otherwise, you can get away without them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, SDC. I have to say though that the information re border-radius is not right.  I ran into an issue with border-radius on Firefox 13.0 and found I had to use the prefix.

Comment: Really? I'd be surprised --- In fact, FF13 was the version where they *removed* support for the prefixed version and went with only supporting the unprefixed version. And you don't need to rely on CanIUse for that -- see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius where it's document by Mozilla themselves. Quote: `Note: Support for the prefixed version (-moz-border-radius) was removed in Gecko 13.0 (Firefox 13.0 / Thunderbird 13.0 / SeaMonkey 2.10).`

Answer (score 4):

Great question- I couldn't find a global reference for vendor-prefix requirements.

I did a quick search on [**caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/) for the vendor-prefixed properties I'm using in *my* projects, and this is what I found (as of late 2013):

- **border-radius:** not necessary
- **box-shadow:** not necessary
- **box-sizing:** `-moz-` required by current/future chrome
- **transform:** `-webkit-` required by all chrome/webkit browsers
- **gradient:** `-webkit-` required by current android browsers and other recent
- **linear-gradient:** `-webkit-` required by current android browsers and other recent
  box-sizing
- **input-placeholder:** not necessary
- **background-clip:** not necessary
- **user-select:** required by all

(**NOTE:** I defined "not necessary" as not being required by any browser with 1% + global usage)

Feel free to add to this...

---

**PUBLIC SERVICE ANNOUNCEMENT:**
Remember that when using vendor-prefixed properties, they should always come *before* non-vendor-prefixed properties:

Example:

```
textarea { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the collection of different vendor-prefixes of various CSS properties. Also well-done mentioning the order of properties with the non-vendor/standards-property at the end. So many examples on sites out there get it wrong.

Just one small addition, the vendor-prefix for Webkit is not `-web-kit-`, but `-webkit-`. I've fixed that in an edit.

Answer (score 4):

If prefixes are all you're interested in, the awesome http://shouldiprefix.com/ is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The closest possible to a full summary, is making your own selective summary using the [Big JS-Compatibility-Table](http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/), looking at [window.document.documentElement.style](http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/de/home?&property=document.documentElement.style), the object which is used to detect support for a particular CSS Feature.

It will give you a convenient dynamic table of all supported W3C CSS properties, by browser, using the camelCased CSS keyword variant, with the ability to select the browsers you are targeting to support. The *still* in this question being subject to change over time.

The Big JS-Compatibility-Table is not a very well know resource made by @TobiasBuschor, but very handy.
I use this table fairly often to check various properties or apis, or cross-check  with [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) data.

The W3C does not fully track compatibility or what implementors actually do or release. And browser makers themselves, except for perhaps Opera, didn't document this stuff well at all until more recently.

For determining the choice as to what browsers are reasonable to deprecate support for (by removing the vendor prefix which would require them). It's going to depend on a given site's feature requirements.

The somewhat accepted convention as of this writing is that it's ok to deprecate support for any browser not supporting `querySelector`, `localStorage` and `addEventListener`.
Meaning you can safely drop support for Firefox 3.5, IE 8, Safari 3.2, Chrome 3, Opera Presto 10.1  and everything under.

Which is to say, it's a little too early right now to remove vendor prefixes, especially due to the fact millions of users still use Android 2.x or 4.3 devices, running Safari 4.x/5.x levels Android Stock Browsers, or Opera Mini (Presto 11). Those represent about 10% of global browser usage in 2014.

In that category, `border-radius` is pretty much the only one feature pretty safe to drop right now. While you could chose to drop others, if you decide to support only the latest browsers. It would be at your own risk and accountability of breaking compatibility with old browsers still heavily used.

It's going to take quite a few years still, before you can deliberately start dropping prefixes completely.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to bother with this question.

If you are using gulp or grunt, you can use a module that will automatically prefix your css according to your targets (IE8, IE9, Chrome 30, etc ..)

https://github.com/Metrime/gulp-autoprefixer

https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer

Comment: As much as tools are there to help, it's still good to know what exactly it is that they help you with.